# Space Button on textfields , not working Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, flutter-textformfield

We have a web project in flutter and sometimes space button is not working in text form fields.
After refreshing the page, or after a request to server it works again.
This situation is causing unstable environment for our users and thus a lot of complaints.
Is there any official documentation, or solution by flutter for this "sometimes space button cannot be used" problem.
What we notices that, when this problem occurs, fonts are different than it supposed to be, like it's not loaded.
It is not browser specific because problem occurs at

- Chrome
- Firefox
- Safari

Comment: Left/Right Arrow keys are also not working on my side.
Once Tab key is pressed, and then space, left and right keys are working. 
is it Flutter library issue?

Comment: Do you fix it? I am with same error...